# Access combine query

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I have a table in an access database named CombinedBomItems.  It contains the fields:

```
QuoteNumber
ReferenceNumber
MFG
MFGPN
QtyPer
UnitOfMeasure
ReDesignators
Description
PCB
```

In the table there are multiple records with the same MFG and MFGPN.  I need a query that consolidates the QtyPer for the records with matching MFG and MFGPN.  I would like to have the following fields in the output of the query: MFG, MFGPN, Description, UnitOfMeasure, PCB.  Can anyone help me with creating such a query?

Comment: Can you give us a small example of input data and the expected output?

Comment: I have already tried uploading a snapshot of the data.  It said I can't as a safety mechanism since I am a new user and they want to limit spam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query will sum up the QtyPer field and provide the fields you require.  However, in order to be grouped together **every fields value within the grouping must be the same.**

```
TRANSFORM Sum(QtyPer) AS SumOfQtyPer
SELECT MFG, MFGPN, Description, UnitOfMeasure, PCB
FROM CombinedBomItems
GROUP BY MFG, MfgPN, Description, UnitOfMeasure, PCB
PIVOT 'QtyPer'
```

Comment: I don't know much about SQL.  I will give your answer a try and let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: Hey Linger it worked.  However the descriptions being different may be a problem.  I think we will have to fix that up on our end though.